A pawn moves across the fields of the board. Expected value of the number of moves after which the pawn will visit all fields.
A pawn moves across the fields of the board in the figure below, in each move, moving to one of the fields bordering a side or corner (each of the available fields has the same probability, the choices for different moves are independent). At the initial moment, the pawn is on field A.

a) Calculate the probability that the pawn will return to A before reaching B or C.
b) Calculate the expected value of the number of moves after which the pawn will visit all fields.

The first subproblem is fairly easy. I create a system of equations containing:

imaginary point A' that is the point where the pawn starts and point A marking pawns return
point L - that is the 'left one' without label - the one that borders A
point R - that is the 'right one' without label - the one that borders L, C and B

Here are the equations:

$p_{A'} = p_L$
$p_L = \frac{1}{3}p_A + \frac{1}{3}p_R + \frac{1}{3}p_C$
$p_R = \frac{1}{3}p_L + \frac{1}{3}p_C + \frac{1}{3}p_B$
$p_A = 1$
$p_C = 0$
$p_B = 0$

From that I get: $p_{A'} = \frac{3}{8}$ and that result seams to be pretty sensible.

I have problem solving the second subproblem. I'm not sure how to track the progress in 'visiting all fields'. I know that I can track the number of steps by adding $+1$ to every equation, that way I get. I can write the whole system of possible moves with counting steps like that:

$p_A = p_L + 1$
$p_L = \frac{1}{3}p_A + \frac{1}{3}p_R + \frac{1}{3}p_C + 1$
$p_R = \frac{1}{3}p_L + \frac{1}{3}p_C + \frac{1}{3}p_B + 1$
$p_C = \frac{1}{3}p_L + \frac{1}{3}p_R + \frac{1}{3}p_B + 1$
$p_B = \frac{1}{2}p_R + \frac{1}{2}p_C$

But how to tackle the challenge of counting only those steps that lead to new field?
That question is similar to other two that I've asked before (I needed my solution to be verified in those):
A pawn moves between the vertices of a square ABCD. Expected number of the move in which the pawn first moves from point B to C. Solution verification
A pawn moves along the vertices of a tetrahedron $ABCD$. Probability that the pawn will return to $A$ before reaching $B$. Solution verification.

For the second problem, you can use the symmetry between B and C to make two variables for each square.  One is the expected number of moves if you have not visited either B or C and the other is the expected number of moves if you have visited one.  Note that when you have visited B and C you have visited all fields.

@RossMillikan Diagonal movement is allowed, there is no symmetry.

Then you have to have three variables per square, visited B, visited C, neither.

@vanderWolf Simulation suggests a value of exactly nine.

One approach would be to set this up as a Markov process, where states are defined by keeping track of the squares that have been visited and the current square. This is tedious to set up (I think you get $19$ states) but once you have the transition matrix the rest is bookwork. This is arguably less elegant than an approach tailored to this particular problem but has the benefit of being easy to do and readily applicable to similar questions.

Let's call the vertices $1,2,3,4,5$ (left to right, with "5" being C and "1" being A). In the first step, the walker visits both "1" and "2", and then the "interesting" story begins. Once the walk at
"2", it takes on average $2$ steps before it jumps to either "3" or "5" (a sort of modified geometric distribution, $\frac23\left(1+3\frac13+5\left(\frac13\right)^2+7\left(\frac13\right)^4+...\right)=2$ using loops $2\to1\to2$.)
You can also notice the symmetry between "3" and "5", so w.l.o.g. assume that after leaving site "2" not to "1",  the walker went to "3". It has spent on average $3=1+2$ units of time by now. Let denote the remaining expected time by $x$.
where:
Let
$y$ be the expected remaining time when all sites but "4" are visited and the walker is at "5" (or at "3", which is the same by symmetry) at the moment;
$z$ be the expected remaining time when all sites but "5" are visited and the walker is at "4" at the moment;
$w$ be the expected remaining time when all sites but "5" are visited and the walker is at "3" at the moment.




Then
$$
x=1+\frac13\left[2+\frac{x+y}2\right]+\frac13z+\frac13y
$$
The three last summands above correspond to steps $3\to2$, $3\to4$ and $3\to5$ respectively.
We also have
$$
y=1+\frac13\left[2+y\right]+\frac13y+\frac13\times 0.
$$
The three last summands above
correspond to steps $5\to2$, $5\to3$ and $5\to4$ respectively.
Similarly,
$$
z=1+\frac12 w +\frac12\times 0.
$$
(the two last summands above correspond to steps $4\to3$ and $4\to5$ respectively)
and
$$
w=1+\frac13\left[2+\frac{w+0}2\right]+\frac13z+\frac13\times 0.
$$
(corresponding to steps to "2", "4", and "5" respectively).
The solution of this system gives
$$
w = 3, \ x = 6,\  y = 5,\ z = 5/2
$$
and the answer is $x+3=9$.

Using similar analysis to the original post, we see that the expected number of moves to have visited $2$ squares is $1$ (e.g. from $A$ you must move to $L$), and the expected number of moves to get from there to having visited $3$ squares is $2$.  Without loss of generality, assume the third square is $C$.
Now there are two possibilities:

$B$ is the last square visited.

$R$ is the last square visited.


Let $p_X,q_X$ be the probability of (1), (2) respectively, from current position $X=A,L,C$ (where $A,L,C$ are the squares that have already been visited).
Again using similar analysis to before, we get $$p_A=p_L=\frac45,p_C=\frac35,\qquad q_A=q_L=\frac15,q_C=\frac25.$$
Now let $R_A,R_L,R_C$ be the expected number of moves to reach $R$ from $A,L,C$ respectively, where we regard the "number of moves" to be $0$ if $B$ is reached before $R$.
We have the following system of linear equations:$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
R_A&=&R_L&+&\frac45,\\
R_L&=&\frac13R_A&+&\frac13R_C&+&\frac45,\\
R_C&=&\frac13R_L&+&\frac35.
\end{array}$$
Here, for $X=A,L,C$, we equate $R_X$ to $p_X$ plus the sum over neighbours $Y$ of $X$, of the probability of moving from $X$ to $Y$ on the next move, multiplied by $R_Y$ (where $R_Y$ is taken to be $0$ if $Y=R$ or $Y=B$).  This is similar to where you added a bunch of $1$'s in the original post.  To see why we add $p_X$ rather than $1$, just recall the definition of expectation as sum over all possibilities of probability of possibility (e.g. product of probabilities of each move in the sequence) multiplied by resulting value of the number of moves.
Solving the system, we get $R_C=1\frac9{25}$.
Now assuming the squares visited already are $A,L,C,R$, let $E_X$ denote the expected number of moves till $B$ is hit, starting from $X$, for $X=A,L,C,R$.  By symmetry, $E_R=E_C$, so we get:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
E_A&=&E_L&+&1,\\
E_L&=&\frac13E_A&+&\frac13E_C&+&\frac13E_C&+&1,\\
E_C&=&\frac13E_L&+&\frac13E_C&+&1.
\end{array}$$
Solving this system, we get $E_R=5$.
Now repeat this analysis for possibility (2):
Let $B_A,B_L,B_C$ be the expected number of moves to reach $B$ from $A,L,C$ respectively, where we regard the "number of moves" to be $0$ if $R$ is reached before $B$.
We have the following system of linear equations:$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
B_A&=&B_L&+&\frac15,\\
B_L&=&\frac13B_A&+&\frac13B_C&+&\frac15,\\
B_C&=&\frac13B_L&+&\frac25.
\end{array}$$
Solving the system, we get $B_C=\frac{16}{25}$.
Now assuming the squares visited already are $A,L,C,B$, let $F_X$ denote the expected number of moves till $R$ is hit, starting from $X$, for $X=A,L,C,B$.  We get:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
F_A&=&F_L&+&1,\\
F_L&=&\frac13F_A&+&\frac13F_C&+&1,\\
F_C&=&\frac13F_L&+&\frac13F_B&+&1,\\
F_B&=&\frac12F_C&+&1.
\end{array}$$
Solving this system, we get $F_B=\frac52$.
Finally, putting it all together, the total expected number of moves required to visit every square is:
$$
1+2+\left(R_C+p_CE_R\right)+\left(B_C+q_CF_B\right)=9.
$$

"Without loss of generality, assume the third square is B": Did you mean $R$ or $C$ here (and thus also in the subsequent analysis)? $B$ can't be reached directly from $L$

@Milten I have swapped all the B's and C's.  Thanks.
